Error 400 on Variation Quantum Algorithm
As the title suggests, I am trying to optimize a cost function in a VQA (Variational Quantum Algorithm) code using a classical optimizer to obtain the best parameters. In my initial optimization attempts, I was able to calculate the value of the cost function successfully. However, I suddenly encountered an error during one of the calculations as follows:
qiskit_ibm_runtime.exceptions.IBMRuntimeError: 'Failed to run program: \'400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.quantum.ibm.com/runtime/jobs. {"errors":[{"code":1217,"message":"Session has been closed.","solution":"Reduce time between submitting subsequent jobs in a session.","more_info":"https://docs.quantum-computing.ibm.com/errors"}]}\''

Despite my numerous attempts to resubmit the code, the problem still persists. It seems to suggest that I waited too long and the session was closed directly. How should I solve this problem?

What are your version numbers for qiskit-ibm-runtime, qiskit-ibm-provider, and qiskit?

Sorry for the late reply.
my qiskit-ibm-runtime = 0.23.0, qiskit = 1.1.0, and i find there's no ibm-provider in my environment. I use QiskitRuntimeService to choose backend. Is that be the problem?

This may be due to the changes that IBM made to sessions on 29 April: https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/announcements/product-updates/2024-04-22-session-changes The Open Plan will execute in job mode with a time limit between jobs, as well as a total time limit.

Thanks! It's really helpful!

I'm glad that it was useful! If this resolves your question, it would be much appreciated if you could mark the answer as accepted. Thank you
